# In Python and numpy, How do I replace missing values in an array with the previous element? (Masked array?)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace

I am pretty new to Python, so thank you in advance for your help with this noob question.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(30)
a[5]=a[10]=0
print a
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  0, 16, 17, 18, 19,  0, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

How could I change the zeros to be the preceding value?  I know I can easily change the zeros to a constant by:

```
a[a==0]=3
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  3, 16, 17, 18, 19,  3, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

but I am looking for something that will return me:

```
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

I've a feeling it has something to do with masked arrays, but I can't find any examples of the sort by googling.  Thank you.

---

In answer to @DSM's question, the first value will never be a zero, but there may be a string of contiguous zeros.

So I'd like to be able to transform:

```
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  0,  0,  0, 18, 19,  0, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

into

```
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

Comment: Will 0 ever be the first value?  If so, what do you want to happen? Will there ever be a group of contiguous zeros?

Comment: 0 will never be the first value but there may be contiguous zeroes.  I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handling contiguity was tricky.  How about:

```
def fill_from_left(a, x=0):
    to_fill = (a == x)
    if a[0] == x:
        raise ValueError("cannot have {} as first element".format(x))
    if to_fill.any():
        lefts = ~to_fill & (np.roll(a, -1) == x)
        fill_from = lefts.cumsum()
        fill_with = a[np.where(lefts)[0]][fill_from - 1]
        a[to_fill] = fill_with[to_fill]
```

which gives

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,0,4,0,0,5])
>>> fill_from_left(a)
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5])
```

---

To be honest, though, most of the time when I have "missing values" it's because I'm working with real data, in which case I tend to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) instead of bare `numpy`.  And `Series` are much easier to fill than `ndarray`s: this would simply be `s.replace(0, np.nan).ffill()`.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `numpy.roll` to shift all the values of an array to the left by one, and then use `numpy.where`:

```
>>> a=np.arange(10, 25)
>>> a[5]=a[10]=0
>>> a
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  0, 16, 17, 18, 19,  0, 21, 22, 23, 24])
>>> np.where( a == 0, np.roll( a, 1 ), a )
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

Comment: This is a good answer, thank you, but what about in the case of contiguous zeroes (please see the edit I've added to the bottom of my original question)